# How to make container take full height of content with overlay?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a container element with an absolutely positionend overlay.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: : 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
  </div>
  <div class='overlay'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need this absolutely positioned div because I need a green transparent overlay effect.

Inside the container, I have content. The content should be free of the 0.5 green transparency and show colors as is.

The problem is to do this, I have to make a div for the content and absolutely position it as well. This causes the container not taking the full height of it's content. So, the container should take the height of the content and the content should not have a 0.5 green overlay over the content.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo element `:after` for the overlay. No need to use extra div for this. Also play with `z-index` value to show the content inside it above overlay.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  width: : 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h1>foobar</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position your `.content` element as relative and then set the z-index value for it higher than the `.overlay`'s z-index value, by default it is set to auto or 0:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: : 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
   <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='overlay'>
  </div>
</div>
```